# Website showing 404 instead of automatically showing index.html

Tags: openlitespeed

I use OpenLiteSpeed as a web server, and when I load my website I get a 404 error instead of it automatically loading the index.html page, when I put index.html in manually the page loads without a problem

Comment: Does the site have PHP? If so, rename index.html to index.php.

Comment: Check https://serverfault.com/